# Is every set of measure zero countable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

I know it is true that every countable set has measure zero, but is the converse true. Is it true that every set of measure zero is countable?

Comment: You could have gotten the answer from Google in less time it took you to post this.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459849/examples-of-uncountable-sets-with-zero-lebesgue-measure and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610098/example-of-an-uncountable-dense-set-with-measure-zero

Comment: If one does not know the answer to this question it might be difficult to predict that in advance @symplectomorphic

Answer (score 7):

No. The [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is probably the easiest example of an uncountable null set.

Of course, there are many others. For instance, every Lebesgue measurable set is a union of a Borel set and a null set.

Answer (score 7):

No, and it's not necessary to jump to the Cantor set (which requires some intense mathematics) in order to see this. Think of a line (such as $\Bbb R \times \{0\}$) in $\Bbb R^2$ - it is a null set, but clearly not countable.

In general, if you have at least a vague intuitive idea of the concept of "dimension", everything that is of dimension $\lneq n$ is a null set in $\Bbb R^n$ (with respect to the usual topological and measurable structures) - and most of these subsets are clearly not countable.

Answer (score 0):

countable sets are measure zero by definition of measure zero because countable sets we can always use a union of interval with arbitrarily small sum of length to cover it. However, measure zero is not always countable, for example cantor set.

Comment: ...Which is exactly what has been already said above, so why post this?